# Make global variable accessible in Robot Framework listener

Tags: jira, robotframework, jira-xray

In one of my projects weare using Robot Framework and a special listener to push results via XRAY to Jira.

Now, we want to call Robot Framework in two different modes named A or B, and different labels need to pushed via XRay to Jira.

I don't want to set some environment variables prior to call robot, as they are really hard to track.

What might be the easiest way to make a global variables of a Robot Framework run accessible in a Robot Framework listener.

I just want to call robot something like this:

```
robot --listener XRayListener.py --variable Mode:A
```

How, can I now access the variable Mode inside of XRayListener.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed in [this article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/the-listener-interface-of-the-robot-framework/) , from the listener python code you can use BuiltIn().get_variables() to obtain a given variable value.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

def end_test(name, attributes):
    print("BROWSER = '%s'" % BuiltIn().get_variables()['${BROWSER}'])
```

Then run it as:

```
robot --listener ShowVariable simple.robot
```

The robot file, just for mere  reference was:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${URL}            https://www.google.com/
${REMOTE_URL}     http://192.168.56.1:4444/wd/hub
${BROWSER}        Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Confirm login popup is accessable
    #Go To    ${URL}
    open browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    set window size    350    800
    [Teardown]    Close Browser(base
```